# type aliasing and similar types

Tags: c++, c++11

On [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) it is said that two pointers are the same if ignoring the top level cv qualifiers they point to the same type. In the examples then there is this example

```
int (* const *)(int *) and int (* volatile *)(int *) are similar;
```

I was wondering how are those supposed to be similar? AFAIK those represent a pointer to a pointer to a function, to simiplify they could be rewritten as

```
 using XYZ = int(*)(int *);
 const XYZ *;     // A
 volatile XYZ *;  // B
```

Aren't A and B pointers to different types in that case?

Comment: Yes, but "different" does not preclude "similar". Or maybe I'm missing the point of the question?

Comment: I think its just a thing of definition of the term `similar`. If you ignore the `(*const*)` and `(*volatile*)` they are the same, but as they are, how they are, they are similar by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On cpp reference it is said that two pointers are the same if ignoring the top level cv qualifiers they point to the same type

Not quite. It says:

> Informally, two types are similar if, ignoring top-level cv-qualification:
>
> - they are the same type; or
> - they are both pointers, and the pointed-to types are similar; or

Note that **same** is not same as **similar**.

---

> ```
> const XYZ *;     // A
> volatile XYZ *;  // B
> ```
>
> Aren't A and B pointers to different types in that case?

They are different types indeed. But they are similar.

Comment: so in other words ignoring the cv qualifiers for the pointed to types as well?

Comment: @mkmostafa yes. That follows from `they are both pointers, and the pointed-to types are similar` rule because the cv qualifiers are ignored regarding similarity of the pointed type.